# How I can reach this chest at Pirate Stronghold?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

There's a chest at Pirate stronghold which I can't reach.  It's in the area where platforms emerge from the sand when you'e carrying the time stone.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the chest you're talking about?  Your description is a little lacking and it's hard to tell which one you're talking about.

Comment: awhhh let me look for it

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://i42.tinypic.com/io0yub.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You walk with the time crystal as close to the chest as possible without making it disappear, then drop the crystal, and walk over to the chest.

This technique will prove useful throughout the Pirate Stronghold.

Comment: Awht ty so much!-how could I miss that!- really thanks